# Select rows using IN condition and group by

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have the following table, which store the suggestion_id and goal_id

```js
id|goal_id|suggestion_id
1 |     12|   1
2 |     13|   2
2 |     17|   2
3 |     14|   1
4 |     15|   3
5 |     16|   3
6 |     12|   4
6 |     18|   4
```

I'd like to query the suggestion_id for a specific combination of goal_ids.

For instance:

- goal_id(13, 17) => i need the suggestion id: 2
- goal_id(12, 14) => i need the suggestion id: 1
- goal_id(14, 12) => i need the suggestion id: 1
- goal_id(12, 18) => i need the suggestion id: 4

Is it even possible to query the suggestion_id this way, or i have to redesign my table?
(I'm using PostgreSQL database)

INPUT: (12, 14) or (14, 12) the order of ids may be change

```
select suggestion_id from table WHERE goal_id IN(12, 14) group by suggestion_id
```

The query returns the following  id: 1,1,4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt's answer works if you want subset matches and are looking for exactly 2 (or `n` items).  However, if you want entire matches, such as 12 and 14 *and nothing else* then I would suggest a variation on the approach.  Assuming that the table does not have duplicates:

```
select suggestion_id
from t
group by suggestion_id
having array_agg(goal_id order by goal_id) = array[12, 14];
```

Note that the use of arrays makes it easy to pass in any number of values.  You can also tweak this to use arrays for a subset match:

```
select suggestion_id
from t
where goal_id = any(array[12, 14])
group by suggestion_id
having array_agg(goal_id order by goal_id) = array[12, 14]
```

Or in this case, you can use array lengths in the `having` clause:

```
having count(*) = cardinality(array[12, 14])
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff! This is exactly what I wanted. It works well, but i don't understand why.. For instance what is the purpose of this line: "goal_id order by goal_id"

Answer (score 2):

`WHERE` clauses are applied to individual rows, not groups.

- the `IN` is essentially `WHERE goal_id = 12 OR goal_id = 14`

What you need is a second filter that says `but only groups which have Both of these`

```
  select suggestion_id
    from table
   where goal_id IN (12, 14)
group by suggestion_id
  having count(distinct goal_id) = 2
```

The `HAVING` clause is applied ***after*** aggregation to groups. So, now we can count how many distinct goals are in the group, and only keep groups which have exactly 2 different goals.

`distinct` is just in case one `suggestion_id` can have the same `goal_id` associated to it more than once.

Note: If your `IN()` list had more than 2 items, you'd need to update the `=  2` as well.

Comment: Thank you MatBailie for your answer!